# Subtract rows and create new columns with results

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subtraction

I have an issue with one SQL query in MySQL. My table looks like below:

```
Index User  Date                   Speed  
1     X     2018-01-01 10:00:00    23
1     X     2018-01-01 10:00:20    50
1     X     2018-01-02 10:00:00    40
1     Z     2018-01-01 10:00:00    20
1     Z     2018-01-02 10:00:00    40
1     Z     2018-01-03 10:00:00    50
```

and result should be like this:

```
Index User  Date                   Speed  Date_diff  Speed_diff
1     X     2018-01-01 10:00:00    23     
1     X     2018-01-01 10:00:20    50     20s          27
1     X     2018-01-01 10:02:00    40     1m40s        -10
1     Z     2018-01-01 10:00:00    20     -2m          -20
1     Z     2018-01-02 10:00:00    40     1d           20
1     Z     2018-01-03 10:00:00    50     1d           10
```

So basically I need to substract rows one after another and create a new columns one with results. I am starting an adventure with SQL and I am not sure how I could do this? Any idea?

I tried to do this using this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag but I think that my syntax is wrong

```
SELECT objid, 
       LAG(Date) OVER AS 'lag',
       LEAD(Speed) OVER AS 'Lead',
       date- LAG(date) OVER AS 'lag diff',
       speed- LEAD(speed) OVER AS 'Lead diff',
FROM tabel;
```

Comment: Question is tagged `mysqli` - are you expecting an answer in SQL or a PHP?

Comment: Python, I am usinng spark.sql(Select * From....).to_Pandas()

Comment: But the syntax should be very familiar

Comment: I think window functions are the way to go: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag

Comment: Use ```LAG(column) OVER (ORDER BY user, `Date`)``` for to access "previous" value. PS. Real needed sorting is absolutely unclear.

Comment: And you don't care about partitioning by user ?

Comment: I don't care about it

Comment: What version of mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT Index, User, 'Date', Speed, 
       'Date' - LAG('Date') OVER w AS Date_diff,
       Speed - LAG(Speed) OVER w AS Speed_diff
FROM table
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY User, 'Date');
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use single quotes for string and date values -- never for column names.

Your code also needs a windowing clause, and to adjust the date/time arithmetic.  If you can represent the date/time difference as a `time`, then:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       secs_to_time(to_seconds(t.date) - LAG(to_seconds(t.date)) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY DATE)) AS date_diff
       (t.speed - LAG(speed) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY DATE)) as speed_diff
FROM tabel t;
```